# Which type of certificate for encrypting SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, ssl-certificate

Does it matter?  We buy our certificates from Thawte, and I don't see a special type of certificate for SQL Server as opposed to a certificate you'd buy for a web server.

Please be gentle with me if this is a dumb question.  I'm a developer, not a server specialist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never mind.  I found the answer on this page:  http://www.thawte.com/resources/ssl-information-center/ssl-beyond-ecommerce/index.html

in the **Server to Server Communications** section.

The answer is "No, there is not a different type of SSL certificate.  You would use the same type of SSL Certificate you would use on a web server."

Sorry to have bothered you.  I should have searched harder.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean the certificate used to encrypt TDS connections (ie. T-SQL connections), as opposed to the certificates used to encrypt DBM or SSB connections.

On TDS connections the client will validate the certificate to be trusted and to have an **Issued To** property matching the connection computer name. In order to be valid the certificate has to be signed by an authority that is trusted by the client. That means either:

- you use a PKI infrastructure that uses a corporate trusted key (ie. a Certificate Server)
- use a certificate signed by an authority trusted by default, already in the root trust list, like Verisign or Thawte
- use a self signed certificate and install the certificate in every client machine

See [How to enable SSL encryption for an instance of SQL Server by using Microsoft Management Console](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/316898?p=1)

Comment: @Remus Rusanu... Thank you, You assume right, and the link you posted is where we got our information from. My question wasn't as clear as I needed it to be, I guess. In your bulleted list, we are going with option 2. My question, specifically, is "Is there a special type of certificate used for this application, or do we just use a standard SSL certificate, such as we would use for a web server?

Comment: For example, I know that Thawte sells SSL Certs for providing SSL on a web server, and also code signing certs.  I also found a type for securing your email, which is a different type: http://www.thawte.com/resources/personal-email-certificates/index.html?click=DoYouNeedTo-SecureMail.   Is there another type for securing a SQL Server, etc?

Comment: I'll give you a +1 for accuracy, even though it didn't answer the question.

Comment: SQL Server uses SChannel SSPI to establish an encrypted channel. In other words, it *actually uses SSL*. By all means, an SSL cert used for HTTPS/IIS should be usable by SQL Server as well, as it is the same SSPI provider that will gets used. That being said, I have never actually tried a Thawte cert myself (I'm not an operational kind of person).